# Google Analytics- Count amount of pageviews before event happens

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like to track  the amount of searches a user has done in Google Analytics, before clicking on a specific buttton, so I can save this in the value of an event.

So the event would be something like this:

```
Event Category: Search
Event Action: Place order
Label: Amount of searches
Value : 10
```

I also use Google Tag Manager, but I'm fairly new to it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this in the GTM/GA. But you can use GTM Custom HTML tag to deploy a simple script that will count the number of searches with the help of cookie/sessionStorage so it could be later accessible as GTM User-defined variable